# System.Diagnostics.Process closing powershell immediately

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, installation, windows-installer

I have an issue where I'm trying to deploy a driver installation via an MSI Installer, it contains the .CAT and .INF files and outputs them to a directory, typically from here an infrastructure engineer could right click the .INF file and press install, however we're trying to streamline this process and automate this step.

Via C# I have a class utilising the System.Diagnostics.Process namespace to spawn a powershell process to run a powershell script containing a simple command as follows:

```
var process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

var newProcessInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

string powerShellScript = @"C:\PowershellScript\DriverInstall.ps1"

newProcessInfo.FileName = @"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"

newProcessInfo.Verb = "runas";  
string newArgs = "-File " + powerShellScript;
newProcessInfo.Arguments = newArgs;
process.StartInfo = newProcessInfo;
process.Start();
```

Powershell script command is as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\DriverLocation" -Recurse -Filter "*inf" | ForEach-Object {PNPUtil.exe /add-driver $_.FullName /install }
```

when running this from powershell it works as expected, however if I try and spawn a powershell process from a C# class it doesn't work, comes up with some red error message text but the process windows spawns and closes immediately so I can't identify what the error is.

Essentially I either need the output from the powershell process to a text file or I need the powershell window to persist so I can identify why the script won't work when running from the System.Diagnostics.Process namespace.

I have tried editing the registries so that powershell will remain open to no avail.

Please don't suggest using the System.Management.Automation.Powershell namespace because utilisation of .NET core is unavailable in our project scenario.

Thanks for taking the time to read this, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: The power shell script has to be in same folder as the c# executable or you need path of the script : string newArgs = "-File " + powerShellScript;

Comment: I have now added the powershell script path, I had omitted this line as I hadn't thought it necessary for answering the question.

Comment: To debug open a cmd.exe window.  The use cmd/K executable.  The capital K option keeps the window open after the executable terminates so you can read the error.  I suspect an environmental variable is missing.

Comment: How would I implement dev/null?

Comment: Utilisation of .NET core is unavailable in our project scenario, we only operate on Windows and therefore Unix/Linux is out of the question I'm afraid.

Comment: Sorry,  I posted wrong answer.  Did you try : cmd/K {your executable file name}

Comment: No problem, thanks for your efforts regardless. Unfortunately the process immediately closes when trying to run through cmd/K also.

Comment: So the window stays open?  Which means the code is failing before any output statements which give some useful information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution was to specify the execution policy within the powershell script, when running from the powershell window it had local admin rights and therefore didn't need an execution policy specified, however because it was being spawned from a separate process it only had remote access rights, therefore it wouldn't allow the script to execute.. never managed to output the particular error message but by process of elimination identified the resolution.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope LocalMachine
```